# merge neighbour identical tags in one

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I paste text from word and in html I see

```
<em>O</em> <em>tempora!</em> <em>O</em> <em>mores!</em>
```

I can not find in tinymce doc how I can reduce em tags to

```
<em>O tempora! O mores!</em>?
```

I find merge `paste_merge_formats` but this is not worked for this case

Answer (score 0):

`paste_merge_formats` only works with redundantly nested style tags.

All it does is reduce structures like `<b>abc <b>bold</b> 123</b>` to `<b>abc bold 123</b>`, as the inner encapsulation is redundant.

If your pasted Word content is already structured like that (each word having its *own* individual tag), it's a problem that you'll need to fix on the Word end. TinyMCE is only interpreting exactly what it's given.

Comment: Copy Paste from inDesign to Word and from Word to tinyMCE paragraph with italic style shown every word wrapped in <em></em>. it is Crazy.